# Jqgrid setup error - this.p is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to set up jqgrid for the first time, my js imports are as follows,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.multiselect.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.searchFilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am getting an error that says "this.p is undefined in line 137". I am not sure if I am missing some imports. Any thoughts on this would be great.

Thanks,
Abi

@The corrected import after Oleg's comments,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Still does not seem to be working :(

The modified full code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>.: Sample :.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
/*if ($()) {  

 }*/

 $(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++){
            $("#table1").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
        }
    }
 )

jQuery("#table1").jqGrid({ 
    datatype: "local", 
    height: 250, 
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'], 
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"}, 
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"}, 
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100}, 
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, 
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, 
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, 
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} 
        ], 
    multiselect: true, 
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data" 
});

var mydata = [ 
    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
    {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
    {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
    {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
    {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
    {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
    {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
    {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},         
    {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
 ];

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outerDiv" style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 100%; height: 25%;">Put whatever you want in here</div>
    <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 100%; height: 23%;">
        <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 50%; height: 99%;float:left;">
            <table id="table1"></table>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 50%; height: 99%;float:right;">
            Div Right
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 100%; height: 23%;">
        <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 50%; height: 99%;float:left;">
            Div Left
        </div>
        <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 50%; height: 99%;float:right;">
            Div Right
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 100%; height: 23%;">
        <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 50%; height: 99%;float:left;">
            Div Left
        </div>
        <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 50%; height: 99%;float:right;">
            Div Right
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 0px solid #060606; width: 100%; height: 6%;">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `jquery.searchFilter.js`, `jquery.tablednd.js` and `grid.loader.js` and add loading `grid.locale-en.js` **before** the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

If you do want to use `grid.loader.js` you should examine the file contain and insert after `grid.loader.js` only the JS files which are not included in the `grid.loader.js`. The rule is: no jqGrid modules allowed be loaded twice.

**UPDATED**: You need make some changes in your main JavaScript. The results of my suggestions you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Abhishek.htm).

What should you do:

1. add `<!DOCTYPE ...` before `<html>` element.
2. place the whole your JavaScript code inside of `$(document).ready(function(){` (not only call of `addRowData`).
3. It is more effectife to use [data: mydata](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) prameter of jqGrid as to use [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method.
4. To have full valide strict HTML code I included `<tr><td/></tr>` inside of `<table>` element. How you can verify on [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) the modified code from http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Abhishek.htm has no validation errors.
5. I don't quite understand HTML page design which you use. Nevertheless I added `clear:both;` style for the first div after the `<table>` to go on the next line.

Comment: I tried it as below...but did not work as well :( I am not sure where the issue is still...kind of confusing...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Abhishek: Which error you have now? You have probably the error not only after including of the JavaScript files which you posted. I suppose that the error occur **in another JavaScript file** which define the jqGrid and which you not posted here. Could you post the full code or better the url which can be used to reproduce your problem?

Comment: SOrry I missed that out previously. I have added the full html now. I am using jqgrid 4 and jquery 1.5.2

Comment: @Abhishek: I forget to post you, that I modified my answer with new information (see "UPDATED" part of the answer)